# How to get correct response data from nodejs server in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-pdfkit

this is my first time posting a question on here.
Basically what I'm want to export pdf file with Japan characters from browser using PdfKit(client side). So i need to send font file from server to client by Buffer.Here is my code... this is all using node.js with express:

Server side(Nodejs):

```
function download_font(req, res) {
var fontpath = path.join(__dirname, 'kochi-gothic-subst.ttf');
fs.readFile(fontpath, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {  // If we couldn't read the file for some reason
        res.writeHead(404, {    // Send a 404 Not Found status
            "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"});
        res.write(err.message); // Simple error message body
        res.end();              // Done
    }
    else {      // Otherwise, if the file was read successfully.
        res.writeHead(200,  // Set the status code and MIME type
                           {"Content-Type": 'application/octet-stream'});
        res.write(content); // Send file contents as response body
        res.end();          // And we're done
    }
});
```

Request from client side using javascript:

```
$.get("/log/font").done(function( data ) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

        var doc = new PDFDocument();
        var stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());

        doc.font(blob).fontSize(25).text('武大郎',100, 100);
        doc.end();

        stream.on('finish', function() {
            blob = stream.toBlob('application/pdf');
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = 'test.pdf';

            var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            event.initEvent("click", true, false);
            link.dispatchEvent(event);
        }); 
    });
```

But when running browser display error message : Uncaught Error: Not a supported font format or standard PDF font.

So i check size data from server and client . Here my code to check file size:

```
*$.get("/log/font").done(function( data ) {
        //alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );

        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
        var url  = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = 'kochi-gothic-subst.ttf';

        var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        event.initEvent("click", true, false);
        link.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
```

I see two files are not equal. Anyone can help me to export pdf with Japan characters from Browser side?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that you are passing in a Blob object, where it requires a buffer object.

Try converting the data returned from your ajax call to an array buffer by using the str2ab function here:
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String

Then pass that into your doc.font() function.

On the server side you could try using express middleware to serve a static font file (to simplify things):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Put the font in your public directory and request from there.

Comment: Thank for you reply Vinnie Pepi, but Its still not work.